# How to Make Text Appear When Pressing a JButton

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, jbutton

I am trying to make an application that displays text when a JButton is pressed, but I can't figure out how, here's my code. It's an application to help someone cheer up. I am using Eclipse if that helps.

```
public LoveYou() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(200, 200, 900, 600);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(200, 200, 200, 200));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Feeling down? Press me.");
    btnNewButton.setActionCommand("enter");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);
    btnNewButton.setBackground(Color.green);
    btnNewButton.setForeground(new Color(30, 144, 255));
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    public void onActionPerformed(ActionEvent e; {
        boolean isClicked = false;
        if(!isClicked){
             isClicked = true;
           System.out.println("Someone loves YOU!");
          }
        else {
            System.out.println("");
     }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `btnNewButton.addActionListener((ActionListener) this);` and try this:

```
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            boolean isClicked = false;
            if (!isClicked) {
                isClicked = true;
                System.out.println("Someone loves YOU!");
            } else {
                System.out.println("");
            }

        }
    });
```